# Sort users by their meta data's value

Tags: php, mysql

Have a table like this:

**users tbl:**

```
id | email
1  | email@example.com
2  | abc@example.com
```

And profile table:

**profiles tbl:**

```
user_id | name | value
1       | name | John
1       | age  | 24
2       | name | Ana
```

Is there a way to sort the users by their profile name? I want the end result to be something like this:

```
2 | abc@example.com | Ana
1 | email@example.com | John
```

Sorted by their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just join the tables as usual and order by `profiles.value`.

```
SELECT users.id,
       users.email,
       profiles.value AS user_name,
INNER JOIN profiles
    ON users.id = profiles.user_id AND
       profiles.name = "name"
ORDER BY profiles.value;
```